# %within% in case_when() under group_modify() not working

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I have the following kind of data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)


data <- tibble(a = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3),
               b = c('x', 'y', 'z', 'z', 'z', 'z', 'z'),
               c = c('ps', 'ps', 'qs', 'rs', 'rs', 'rs', 'rs'),
               d = c(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700),
               strt = ymd(c('2019-03-20', '2020-01-01', '2018-01-02', '2020-05-01', '2016-01-01', '2020-03-01', '2020-01-01')),
               fnsh = ymd(c('3019-03-20', '3020-01-01', '3018-01-02', '2020-06-01', '2016-05-01', '2020-04-01', '2020-06-10')))
```

I am doing a group-wise operation based on the variables a, b and c (i.e. `data %>% group_by(a, b, c)`) using `group_modify()`. For each group, I need to find the rows with genuine starting dates within the last year. A strt is genuine if it doesn't fall between the strt and fnsh of any other row in the group. My current approach is:

```
test <- data %>%
  group_by(a, b, c) %>%
  group_modify(function(.x, .y) {
               .x %>%
               mutate(startLatestYear = case_when(strt > today(tzone = 'CET') - years(1) &
                                                  strt <= today(tzone = 'CET') &
                                                  !strt %within% (.x %>%
                                                                  mutate(pushInterval = interval(strt + days(1), fnsh)) %>%
                                                                  select(pushInterval)) ~ 1,
                                                  TRUE ~ 0))}) %>%
  ungroup()
```

This approach gives:

```
data <- tibble(a = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3),
               b = c('x', 'y', 'z', 'z', 'z', 'z', 'z'),
               c = c('ps', 'ps', 'qs', 'rs', 'rs', 'rs', 'rs'),
               d = c(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700),
               strt = ymd(c('2019-03-20', '2020-01-01', '2018-01-02', '2020-05-01', '2016-01-01', '2020-03-01', '2020-01-01')),
               fnsh = ymd(c('3019-03-20', '3020-01-01', '3018-01-02', '2020-06-01', '2016-05-01', '2020-04-01', '2020-06-10')),
               startLatestYear = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1))
```

What is needed is:

```
data <- tibble(a = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3),
               b = c('x', 'y', 'z', 'z', 'z', 'z', 'z'),
               c = c('ps', 'ps', 'qs', 'rs', 'rs', 'rs', 'rs'),
               d = c(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700),
               strt = ymd(c('2019-03-20', '2020-01-01', '2018-01-02', '2020-05-01', '2016-01-01', '2020-03-01', '2020-01-01')),
               fnsh = ymd(c('3019-03-20', '3020-01-01', '3018-01-02', '2020-06-01', '2016-05-01', '2020-04-01', '2020-06-10')),
               startLatestYear = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1))
```

The group based on `a == 3`, `b == 'z'` and `c == 'rs'` has a row (the very last row) that should be the only row in the group with 1 in startLatestYear.
 The very last row is the only row in the group which has strt within the latest year and strt outside the intervals from the other rows in the group.

The first two conditions in the present use of `case_when()` seem to work. The third condition using `%within%` does not seem to work. How can the condition using `%within%` come to work? Or how can an alternative solution be implemented?

PS: I have tried making pushInterval before grouping the tibble. Doing so produces the same column for startLatestYear, but the operation leads to the 'problem' of `bind_rows_()` stripping away the interval attributes. Hence the current solution that produces pushInterval on the fly.

Comment: The "rules" in your second paragraph (within a year, no overlaps) are different than the fifth paragraph (`strt` before other `strt`s, `fnsh` after other `fnsh`s). Please clarify the constraints you are using.

Comment: Correct. I have edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to use `group_modify`, this works in a simple group `mutate`:

```r
data %>%
  group_by(a, b, c) %>%
  mutate(x = +(purrr::map_lgl(strt, ~ sum(strt <= .x & .x <= fnsh) < 2) &
                 difftime(Sys.time(), strt, "days") < 365)) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 7 x 7
#       a b     c         d strt       fnsh           x
#   <dbl> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <date>     <date>     <int>
# 1     1 x     ps      100 2019-03-20 3019-03-20     0
# 2     1 y     ps      200 2020-01-01 3020-01-01     1
# 3     2 z     qs      300 2018-01-02 3018-01-02     0
# 4     3 z     rs      400 2020-05-01 2020-06-01     0
# 5     3 z     rs      500 2016-01-01 2016-05-01     0
# 6     3 z     rs      600 2020-03-01 2020-04-01     0
# 7     3 z     rs      700 2020-01-01 2020-06-10     1
```

`.x` is the placeholder for the parameter passed as the first argument to `map_lgl`. In this case, it's also `strt`, but let's forget about that for a moment.

Inside of the tilde-function, `strt` refers to the whole vector, and `.x` is referring to each individual `strt` value (it is always length 1). `strt <= .x` the first time is effectively `strt <= strt[1]`. The `sum` just counts how many of the occurrences are true. (There should always be *one*, since a number will always be within its own range.)

Comment: It turns out that ```~ sum(strt <= .x & .x <= fnsh) < 2``` doesn't act as I thought it did. An explanation of how it works would be much appreciated.